# Camel Caps SOAP method names

Tags: soap

One of my co-workers is developing SOAP API for php application and he is wondering if CamelCaps names are some kind of convention for SOAP methods?

Our current API has lower_caps_and_underscores, but it seems somewhat strange when compared with random subset of other SOAP APIs, and we wouldn't really want to annoy consumers of API with our wrong convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In almost all standard SOAP API, I have seen, had CamelCaps. You may want to look standard SOAP API. i.e. google SOAP api

I think so Underscore may annoy users. You can follow either of them however more important is to follow any single standard naming conventions.

Other important thing to consider for naming a service is, naming should clearly establish a meaning and a context of the what service will do in a particular context.

i.e.

GetCustomerHistoryById = Get a single customers history by id
GetCustomersHistory = Get all customer's history

Answer (score 1):

What language are you developing in (not that it matters)?

From my experience lower_with_underscores seems to be the preferred style for PHP development, but CamelCase seems to be more generally used.

Just a thought

Answer (score 1):

For SOAP, you see either Pascal Casing or Camel Casing. The SOAP namespace is Pascal Cased (soap:Envelope anyone). I guess what you use depends on where you draw the line.

In general, I use Pascal Casing for Methods and Properties. These two elements embody the framework of the contract. Bearing this in mind, I would likely have SOAP elements that correspond to Methods and Properties Pascal Cased.

As for parameters and return values, I would have to think about breaking the Pascal casing rule and using camel casing there. Fortunatley, I am not building a SOAP API right now, so I have time to think about it.

I would not go with something outside of Pascal or Camel casing, however, as it is non standard. Not that I think people would say "I am not using YOUR API because it uses non-standard naming", but just as a matter of convention. But, then, people who buck convention often come up with the next new trend in development. ;-)